# symfony2 how to save specific data with entity in formbuilder

Tags: symfony

I need to store userinfo for active user represented by `$id`, which I parsed from controller. In this case (in code) I obtain in form list of all users, but I need to obtain only actual user which I work with.

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $id = $this->id;

        $builder
            ->add('companyname')
            ->add('address')
            ->add('city')
            ->add('zip')
            ->add('userinfo', 'entity',  array('property' => 'id', 'class' => 'Admin\SecureBundle\Entity\Userinfo', 'attr' => array('value' => $id), 'empty_value' => $id));
```

idea: I have a user and an invoice address for that user. In database onetoone rel. 
I need to create invoiceaddress of the active user - id of this user should be stored in userinfo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [Symfony2-Doc about the entity form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html):

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.isActive = 1')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

You need to make your own query here.